# add zeros to odd indexes of a 2D raay in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array and I want to insert zeros between each element in this array. something like below:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
```

I want to have something like below:

```
Result1 = [[1,0,2,0,3],
           [0,0,0,0,0],
           [4,0,5,0,6],
           [0,0,0,0,0],
           [7,0,8,0,9],
           [0,0,0,0,0],
           [10,0,11,0,12]]
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using pandas: `df.reindex_axis(np.arange(len(df) * 2 - 1) / 2).reindex_axis(np.arange(len(df.columns) * 2 - 1) / 2, 1).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new array of zeros, and fill values from `A` to this new array every other row/column with slice notation:

```
result = np.zeros((2 * A.shape[0] - 1, 2 * A.shape[1] - 1), np.int16)
result[::2, ::2] = A

result
#array([[ 1,  0,  2,  0,  3],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 4,  0,  5,  0,  6],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [ 7,  0,  8,  0,  9],
#       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#       [10,  0, 11,  0, 12]], dtype=int16)
```